# Mapbox GL-JS : Mapbox icon's z-index

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a web-app going and I want the Mapbox attribution to be in the bottom-right corner. This is obviously easy to do, but the problem is the logo is behind my menu, as seen below :

[image]

Is it possible to access the logo in CSS so that I can properly make the logo on top of all the other content? I want to follow Mapbox guidelines as much as possible. In the image I attached it looks grey because it is behind a semi-transparent menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing "inspect element" on the logo reveals that its styling is controlled through the `a.mapboxgl-ctrl-logo` selector. You can add your own override styles to that.